# Why can't I hide inherited events the same way I can hide properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got a usercontrol which inherits from the UserControl class. There are a bunch of items I want to hide from anyone who uses the class.

I can hide properties just fine...

```
public partial class userControls_MyControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl {

    private new bool EnableTheming {get; set;}
}
```

This effectively removes it from being displayed in the editor's IntelliSense.

However, when I try the same thing with events, they still show up...

```
public partial class userControls_MyControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl {

    private new EventHandler AbortTransaction { get; set; }
    private new EventHandler OnAbortTransaction {get;set;}
}
```

Is there any way to really hide an event? Why isn't the above working?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to hide a Property that doesn't exist.  You need to use the event syntax this would do it:-

```
 private new event EventHandler AbortTransaction;
```

You might be tempted to use the EditorBrowserable attribute and leave the event public, don't.  That could mean external code might attempt to attach to AbortTransaction on your control but that will not be seen by the inherited control code.

Comment: DOH! I knew it had to be something simple I was missing.

Comment: Gah, also missed the missing "event" keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Try applying `EditorBrowsableAttribute(false)` to your events: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute.aspx

Comment: That's fine but you've got to define them first and that has its own problems.

Comment: I actually tried this with no luck... still shows up in IntelliSense.

Btw Anthony, what "problems" come from defining the events? Sure, the user can no longer use them, but they are so uncommon for us to use that it doesn't do anything negative...